# How can I refresh access tokens using long-lived access tokens in Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to refresh facebook long-lived access token.
I am using allauth for connecting with Facebook and saved long lived access token in the database.
Before expired date, I want to refresh the long-lived access token( without the Facebook login flow.
So how can I refresh token with extended validity or get new token without facebook login?

Comment: you cannot refresh a token without user interaction

Answer (score -1):

You just have to make a GET request using following url by passing the required parameters to it :-
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=YOUR_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN

I hope this will help.